# use mongoDB ObjectID in query parameter, does it affect SEO?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, seo, mean-stack

if we use object id of mongodb in query parameter like for example,

in browser url,

```
http://example.com/get-details/507f191e810c19729de860ea
```

to pass this objectID from one state to another state, I am using $stateparam

then,in $http 
the url will be

```
"/get_details?id="+$stateParams.detail_id

$http.get("/get_details?id="+$stateParams.detail_id).then(...);
```

if there any problem with the url in browser in terms of SEO, i.e,  `http://example.com/get-details/507f191e810c19729de860ea` what could be the solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the seo tag except itself states *"

IMPORTANT: Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com "* and this does not seem to be a programming question.

Comment: @Blakes Seven Thank you for suggesting that, If it is not related to mongoDB, Express or Angular, I would have done that, My Client is telling that the weird looking ObjectID is good for SEO, I have doubt on that, I am Javascript dev and I have no Idea on this SEO stuff, so for clarification I posted

Comment: I mean to say not good for SEO

Comment: We get what you mean, but just because the content in question is a hex string from an `ObjectId` does not a programming question make. You may as well be asking is "abc" or 123 good for SEO? Which is essentially a non-programming question. I believe the point that the non-answer here was trying to make is that `35331189` which would the the "Id" of your question is even backed up with a "slugified" version of the title, and for SEO purposes. But it still does not mean the non programming question is okay here.

Comment: To use MongoDB Object ID like 507f191e810c19729de860ea in a URL not only a huge security issue but it is also very bad for SEO. Don't do it! And don't ask SEO questions on StackOverflow!

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn, I got it, I will not post any query here again regarding SEO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to use MongoDB Object ID as a primary key in a URL, in terms of SEO.

Also please consider including a slugified title along with the Object ID in the URL:

`http://example.com/detail/<Object-ID>/<Slug>`

It makes the URL more readable and helps search engines to determine the content of your page.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I did not get that one

Comment: Can I use ObjectID, is it okay ?

Comment: @Karthik_nodedev Sorry for the late reply. Please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: @Shaung, Thanks for your answer, so In Angular we have the url pattern like this right `http://example.com/#/detail/<Object-ID>/<Slug>`, now the url has # in it so it will not work, suppose if I use html5mode in Angular, is this gona solve the issue, Thanks again

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn that's what my client is saying, are you saying this `http://example.com/detail/<Object-ID>/<Slug>` is wrong (or) html5mode of  this `http://example.com/#/detail/<Object-ID>/<Slug>`, I think then the only choice is secondary Index, can you please share me the solution otherwise

Comment: @Karthik_nodedev For angular please refer to the developer docs: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/guide/$location